# How to get particular string from my table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

My table column contains following sample data:

> /Users/abct2/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/FD301781-D39F-469E-A604-8164CC9A4493/Library/Caches/List3-ROHAN TEST1/word_306:24:50.jpg

Now, I want to extract any text which comes after /Library/Caches/ (that is List3-ROHAN TEST1/word_306:24:50.jpg). How do I write the select statment for this?

Just FYI, text which is preceding /Library/Caches/ can have any number of slashes.

Please let me know..

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you **actually** using?

Comment: The answer for MySQL is different than for T-SQL, and both are different than for PL/SQL.  So, as @MartinSmith asks, which do you want to know the answer for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that "/Library/Caches/" only appears in one position then you can do this:

```
SUBSTR (text, INSTR(text,'/Library/Caches/')+16)
```

There are 16 characters in '/Library/Caches/', so the part you want starts 16 characters after the position of '/Library/Caches/' in text.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is this +16 for?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the amount of text before Library/Cache is not fixed. So will your answer work in that case?

Comment: Updated answer: There are 16 characters in '/Library/Caches/', so the part you want starts 16 characters after the position of '/Library/Caches/' in text.

Comment: Yes, as long as '/Library/Caches/' only appears once in the string my solution will find it and get the remainder of the string after it.

Comment: To be a little more specific it will work if there are multiple occurrences - but only on the first occurrence.  If there are multiple occurrences and you want a specific one you can also do that with INSTR(text,search_text,occurrence (e.g. 2))

Comment: Thanks for help .  For  SQLite how to write above  sql statement